# I need to compare two text files and want to store result in a new file

Tags: batch-file

I need to compare two text files and want to store result in a new file.  This code is not helping.

```
findstr /vixg:oldstatus.txt newstatus.txt > diff.txt
```

Its just giving the output of newstatus.txt. Its not showing the difference.

Comment: What are your actually expecting to see in the results file?Is PowerShell an option?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (oldstatus.txt) do (
findstr /i /v /c:"%%a" newstatus.txt >>diff.txt
)
pause
```

for help with `findstr` command: http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.htm 
also see: http://ss64.com/nt/fc.htm
and: http://ss64.com/nt/comp.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fc` command to show the difference between two files. The `/c` option does a case-insensitive compare like `findstr`'s `/i` option.

```
fc oldstatus.txt newstatus.txt >diff.txt
```

From the output of `fc /?`:

```
Compares two files or sets of files and displays the differences between them


FC [/A] [/C] [/L] [/LBn] [/N] [/OFF[LINE]] [/T] [/U] [/W] [/nnnn]
   [drive1:][path1]filename1 [drive2:][path2]filename2
FC /B [drive1:][path1]filename1 [drive2:][path2]filename2

/A         Displays only first and last lines for each set of differences.
/B         Performs a binary comparison.
/C         Disregards the case of letters.
/L         Compares files as ASCII text.
/LBn       Sets the maximum consecutive mismatches to the specified
           number of lines.
/N         Displays the line numbers on an ASCII comparison.
/OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
/T         Does not expand tabs to spaces.
/U         Compare files as UNICODE text files.
/W         Compresses white space (tabs and spaces) for comparison.
/nnnn      Specifies the number of consecutive lines that must match
           after a mismatch.
[drive1:][path1]filename1
           Specifies the first file or set of files to compare.
[drive2:][path2]filename2
           Specifies the second file or set of files to compare.
```